# Extracting hopping parameters for band structure calculations from Atomic coordinates

Tags: band-structure, lammps

I have relaxed atomic coordinates of bilayer graphene obtained from LAMMPS MD simulations.

I want to extract hopping parameters (tight binding model or continuum model) to obtain the band structure of the system.

Can someone assist me.

Comment: Why you don't calculate the bands directly using any DFT code? Also, you can take a look at the package DFTB+ that implements the  [Density Functional based Tight Binding (DFTB)](https://dftb.org/about-dftb)

Comment: LAMMPS relaxations are widely used nowadays because of the restrictions have in DFT calculations. When we need small twist angle the number of atoms in the simulation box is extremely large. Therefore, we want to use LAMMPS and extract continuum model hopping parameters from the relaxed coordinates

Comment: As (classical) Molecular Dynamics doesn't include the electrons, you cannot obtain any parameter related to them. And of course, band structure only works for periodical systems with electrons. If the system is big, you can use semiempirical methods or divide/conquer methods likes Fragment Molecular Orbitals include in GAMESS-US.

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but since it's been 6+ months I wonder if you can update us? Did the comment by Camps help you figure out the answer? Have you figured out the answer elsewhere? Are you no longer worried about this?

Comment: hii, I'm still trying on that

Comment: @Shen can you be more specific about what you're trying and what you've tried and what remains to be the problem?